# Hide files in a FTP-program

Tags: ftp

I want the users who log in to the web-server via FTP to don't be able to see the files in the root-folder, but all folders and all files in subfolders. This is not for security, only to have a cleaner view.

But I can't find any way to hide the files.

I know it is possible to give the user access only to a certain subfolder, but the users need to see all the folder in the root-folder, so this is't really an option.

It would be OK if there is a way to hide only all .php files.

If the solution require a FTP-program, it should work on both Windows and OS X.

Comment: Can you move all the folders of the root dir to a subfolder, then give the users access to that?

Comment: No, I can't move the folders to a subfolder, thats my big problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the files as hidden by prefixing the "." character to their filenames.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. But it's not an option to change the name of any file or folder.

Comment: Same with filenames on a Linux, Mac, ... OS:
all files starting with a "." are hidden:


Example:
".test.html"   (will not be shown by ls command)

Answer (score 0):

First you sound a bit confused. You cannot login to a webserver using a ftp client. You access a webserver using a webbrowser.

If you want to remove files from the default listing of files that a webserver will produce if there isn't an index file, then perhaps the easiest way is to write a cgi program which will exclude those files you don't want to see, and output the names properly formatted.

Comment: If I wasn't confused I should not asked the question. And I'm not an expert. So I'm sorry if you did not understand my question. Anyway, the users use a FTP-program to see files and transfer files to the server. Is you answer still applicable?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing cannot be achieved on the server. The closest thing you can do with file permissions is hide a non-root directory (and its contents).

However you should be able to [filter](http://www.smartftp.com/features/localbrowser/#filter) the view on any decent FTP client.

[image: Filter]